# Phaser3, Matter physics, Calculate distance between a point and a physics shape

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm currently working on a Phaser 3 game project, using Matter Physics. I created a `matter.image` object. In order to create a physics shapes, which I have to determine the coordinates of each vertex of the polygon outline like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFLYr.png), I used Physics Editor (https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor). It generates a JSON file include vertices, you can refer to *Attachment #1*.

Now I want to calculate **the horizontal distance between the physics shape and a point**. For example, in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jonEu.png), the blue one in the left is physics shape, and the blue one in the left is the point, and the green line is the *horizontal distance* I want to calculate.

Code used to create the object:

```js
// in the preload() function
this.load.json('sprite', '../assets/chisato-sprite.json');

// in the create() function
sprites = this.cache.json.get('sprite');
chisatoLeft = this.matter.add.image(480, 425, 'chisatoLeft', null, { shape: sprites.left });
```

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Attachment #1**  Excerpt of the json file

```json
{
    "generator_info": "Shape definitions generated with PhysicsEditor. Visit https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor",
    "left": {
        "type": "fromPhysicsEditor",
        "label": "left",
        "isStatic": true,
        "density": 0.10000000149011612,
        "restitution": 0,
        "friction": 0.10000000149011612,
        "frictionAir": 0.009999999776482582,
        "frictionStatic": 0.5,
        "collisionFilter": {
            "group": 0,
            "category": 1,
            "mask": 255
        },
        "fixtures": [
            {
                "label": "",
                "isSensor": false,
                "vertices": [
                    [ { "x":71, "y":226.5 }, { "x":76.5, "y":215 }, { "x":57.5, "y":216 } ],
                    [ { "x":166, "y":197.5 }, { "x":182.5, "y":169 }, { "x":164.5, "y":177 } ],
                    [ { "x":33.5, "y":214 }, { "x":29.5, "y":203 }, { "x":24.5, "y":206 } ],
                    [ { "x":198.5, "y":44 }, { "x":176, "y":38.5 }, { "x":162, "y":48.5 }, { "x":175.5, "y":50 } ],
                    [ { "x":175.5, "y":50 }, { "x":162, "y":48.5 }, { "x":168.5, "y":59 } ],
                    [ { "x":61, "y":223.5 }, { "x":57.5, "y":216 }, { "x":29.5, "y":203 }, { "x":47, "y":215.5 } ],
                    [ { "x":192.5, "y":61 }, { "x":168.5, "y":59 }, { "x":173, "y":68.5 } ],
                    [ { "x":159, "y":195.5 }, { "x":164.5, "y":177 }, { "x":173, "y":68.5 }, { "x":156.5, "y":180 } ],
                    [ { "x":129, "y":17.5 }, { "x":86, "y":10.5 }, { "x":85, "y":10.5 }, { "x":29.5, "y":203 }, { "x":156.5, "y":180 }, { "x":173, "y":68.5 }, { "x":168.5, "y":59 }, { "x":162, "y":48.5 } ],
                    [ { "x":20.5, "y":273 }, { "x":17.5, "y":341 }, { "x":26, "y":399 }, { "x":265.5, "y":381 }, { "x":226, "y":234.5 }, { "x":87.5, "y":231 }, { "x":47, "y":249.5 } ],
                    [ { "x":43, "y":219.5 }, { "x":47, "y":215.5 }, { "x":29.5, "y":203 } ],
                    [ { "x":208.5, "y":166 }, { "x":204.5, "y":130 }, { "x":200, "y":140.5 } ],
                    [ { "x":57.5, "y":216 }, { "x":76.5, "y":215 }, { "x":156.5, "y":180 }, { "x":29.5, "y":203 } ],
                    [ { "x":5.5, "y":152 }, { "x":24.5, "y":206 }, { "x":29.5, "y":203 }, { "x":85, "y":10.5 }, { "x":13.5, "y":64 }, { "x":5.5, "y":92 } ],
                    [ { "x":52.5, "y":20 }, { "x":32, "y":35.5 }, { "x":13.5, "y":64 }, { "x":85, "y":10.5 } ],
                    [ { "x":185.5, "y":201 }, { "x":189, "y":199.5 }, { "x":200.5, "y":161 }, { "x":200, "y":140.5 }, { "x":182.5, "y":169 } ],
                    [ { "x":182.5, "y":169 }, { "x":200, "y":140.5 }, { "x":204.5, "y":130 }, { "x":173, "y":68.5 }, { "x":164.5, "y":177 } ],
                    [ { "x":299, "y":400 }, { "x":265.5, "y":381 }, { "x":26, "y":399 } ],
                    [ { "x":87.5, "y":231 }, { "x":226, "y":234.5 }, { "x":217, "y":226.5 }, { "x":152.5, "y":212 }, { "x":92.5, "y":220 } ],
                    [ { "x":152.5, "y":212 }, { "x":156.5, "y":180 }, { "x":76.5, "y":215 }, { "x":92.5, "y":220 } ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the distance between two specific points in Phaser, you can use the Phaser function `Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(x1, y1, x2, y2)` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Math.Distance.html#.BetweenPoints__anchor)).

So you could iterate calculate the point in the world position ( JsonData-Point minus Image position ) and than calculate the distance.

here a possible code snippet, how this could look like.
*(assuming all vertices under of the `vertices` properties are relevant)*

```
let targetPoint = {x:100, y:200};
let listOfDistances = sprites.left.fixtures[0].vertices.flat.map(vertex => {
    return Phaser.Math.Distance.Between( 
        vertex.x - chisatoLeft.x, 
        vertex.y - chisatoLeft.y,
        targetPoint.x,
        targetPoint.y
    );
});
```

**Update 1:** I miss read, if you only need the ***horizontal distances***, you can simply subtract the x-coordinates, something like this:

```
 ...
 let listOfDistances = sprites.left.fixtures[0].vertices.flat().map(vertex => {
    return Math.abs(
        (vertex.x - chisatoLeft.x) -
        targetPoint.x
    );
});
```

> Since a distance can only be a positive number, you would have to use the `Math.abs()` - function ([link to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs))

**And than** just calculate the shortes distance *(= horizontal distance)*, with `Math.min` ([link to documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min))

```
...
let horizontalDistance = Math.min( ...listOfDistances );
...
```

**Update 2:**

If you want to get the intersection, this would be the solution:
*([documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Geom.Intersects.html#.GetLineToPoints__anchor) for the funtion `GetLineToPoints` )*

```
 ...
 let targetPoint = { x: 100, y: 200 };

 let points = sprites.left.fixtures[0].vertices.flat().map(vertex => {
     return new Phaser.Geom.Point(vertex.x - chisatoLeft.x, vertex.y - chisatoLeft.y);
 });
 
 let line = new Phaser.Geom.Line(config.width, targetPoint.y, 0, targetPoint.y);

 let interSectingPoint = Phaser.Geom.Intersects.GetLineToPoints( line, points );

 let horizontalDistance = Math.abs(targetPoint.x - interSectingPoint.x);
```

**Update 3:**

Here a Phaser running example.
*(btw.: for the `line` the start and end point order is important/makes a difference)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

let data = {"fixtures":[{"vertices":[[{"x":71,"y":226.5},{"x":76.5,"y":215},{"x":57.5,"y":216}],[{"x":166,"y":197.5},{"x":182.5,"y":169},{"x":164.5,"y":177}],[{"x":33.5,"y":214},{"x":29.5,"y":203},{"x":24.5,"y":206}],[{"x":198.5,"y":44},{"x":176,"y":38.5},{"x":162,"y":48.5},{"x":175.5,"y":50}],[{"x":175.5,"y":50},{"x":162,"y":48.5},{"x":168.5,"y":59}],[{"x":61,"y":223.5},{"x":57.5,"y":216},{"x":29.5,"y":203},{"x":47,"y":215.5}],[{"x":192.5,"y":61},{"x":168.5,"y":59},{"x":173,"y":68.5}],[{"x":159,"y":195.5},{"x":164.5,"y":177},{"x":173,"y":68.5},{"x":156.5,"y":180}],[{"x":129,"y":17.5},{"x":86,"y":10.5},{"x":85,"y":10.5},{"x":29.5,"y":203},{"x":156.5,"y":180},{"x":173,"y":68.5},{"x":168.5,"y":59},{"x":162,"y":48.5}],[{"x":20.5,"y":273},{"x":17.5,"y":341},{"x":26,"y":399},{"x":265.5,"y":381},{"x":226,"y":234.5},{"x":87.5,"y":231},{"x":47,"y":249.5}],[{"x":43,"y":219.5},{"x":47,"y":215.5},{"x":29.5,"y":203}],[{"x":208.5,"y":166},{"x":204.5,"y":130},{"x":200,"y":140.5}],[{"x":57.5,"y":216},{"x":76.5,"y":215},{"x":156.5,"y":180},{"x":29.5,"y":203}],[{"x":5.5,"y":152},{"x":24.5,"y":206},{"x":29.5,"y":203},{"x":85,"y":10.5},{"x":13.5,"y":64},{"x":5.5,"y":92}],[{"x":52.5,"y":20},{"x":32,"y":35.5},{"x":13.5,"y":64},{"x":85,"y":10.5}],[{"x":185.5,"y":201},{"x":189,"y":199.5},{"x":200.5,"y":161},{"x":200,"y":140.5},{"x":182.5,"y":169}],[{"x":182.5,"y":169},{"x":200,"y":140.5},{"x":204.5,"y":130},{"x":173,"y":68.5},{"x":164.5,"y":177}],[{"x":299,"y":400},{"x":265.5,"y":381},{"x":26,"y":399}],[{"x":87.5,"y":231},{"x":226,"y":234.5},{"x":217,"y":226.5},{"x":152.5,"y":212},{"x":92.5,"y":220}],[{"x":152.5,"y":212},{"x":156.5,"y":180},{"x":76.5,"y":215},{"x":92.5,"y":220}]]}]};

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 100 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {


   let targetPoint = { x: 300, y: 80 };
   let chisatoLeft = { x: 10, y: 10 };

   let points = data.fixtures[0].vertices.flat().map(vertex => {
   console.info(vertex)
       return new Phaser.Geom.Point(vertex.x - chisatoLeft.x, vertex.y - chisatoLeft.y);
   });
   
   console.info(points, data)
   
   // draw points -> just for the demo
   
   points.forEach( point =>
      this.add.rectangle(point.x, point.y, 5, 5, 0xff0000)
   );
   
   // draw target point -> just for the demo
   
   this.add.rectangle(targetPoint.x, targetPoint.y, 8, 8, 0xffffff).setDepth(2);
   
   // draw line -> just for the demo
   
   this.add.line(0, 0, config.width, targetPoint.y, 0, targetPoint.y, 0x00ff00).setOrigin(0);

   let line = new Phaser.Geom.Line(config.width, targetPoint.y, 0, targetPoint.y);

   let interSectingPoint = Phaser.Geom.Intersects.GetLineToPoints( line, points );
   
   // draw line to intersection -> just for the demo
   this.add.line(0, 0, targetPoint.x, targetPoint.y + 10, interSectingPoint.x, targetPoint.y + 10, 0xffffff).setOrigin(0);

   let horizontalDistance = Math.abs(targetPoint.x - interSectingPoint.x);
   
   this.add.text(config.width-10, 10, `horizontalDistance : ${horizontalDistance.toFixed(2)}`).setOrigin(1,0)
   console.info(horizontalDistance);

}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: But why horizontal distances is from subtracting the **y**-coordinates instead of **x**-coordinates?

Comment: @NoNormalCreeper Uppsss, my bad ofcourse `x`, it was a long weekend :)

Comment: check [this figure](https://s1.328888.xyz/2022/09/12/KftGN.jpg).
In your opinion, `ListOfDistance` is `[△x1, △x2, △x3, △x4, ...]`. 
So distance is *△x2*, because it's the minimum value in `ListOfDistance`. 
But in fact, distance should be *△x0*, or less accurate, be *△x4*.

Comment: @NoNormalCreeper I updated my answer, I think this should solve the problem, as show in the new image.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand where is the `line` come from?

Comment: doesn't work, the result is always `targetPoint.x`

Comment: @NoNormalCreeper `line` ist just a horziontal line on the height of the `targetPoint`. Okay, I should have tested the code. here a running example. The problem was, I used `flatMap` instead of `flat()` and than calling the `map` function.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But when `targetPoint` is in the left of `chisatoLeft`, the `horizontalDistance` will be incorrect.

Comment: @NoNormalCreeper, yes that's why I wrote _...start and end point order is important..._ of the `line`, you would just have to have logic checking if the `targetPoint.x` is smaller than the points and "just change the direction" of the `line`. My answer just explains the basic logic, not every case is covered.